# MariaDB 10.0.33 Configuring MariaDB for Remote Client Access

Tags: 16.04, remote-access, mariadb

I just keep verbatim the instructions in MariaDB docs but it does not work at all, and I wast a great ammount of time.

[MariaDB docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/) does not take into account this version in its documentation.

Following the instructions i modified the file my.cnf that in my case it was /etc/mysql/my.cnf

I comment this out as the example, but in my case I had to add it manually.

```
 [mysqld]
    ...
    #skip-networking
    ...
    #bind-address = <some ip-address>
    ...
```

And as I already have an account with remote permissions, I just restarted the mysql service but nothing happened.

**Check if por is open**

```
sudo nmap -PN -p 3306 -sV server_ip
```

The port wasn't listening from remote ips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English
The answer was already in the file my.cnf where it explains the configuration order so that the last file is the one that applies.
The problem I got is that the MariaDB docs recommends to comment out the lines skip-networking and bind-address.
In my case, to comment out lines does nothing, it doesn't override the previous configuration, because it only applies if it defines something new, so I had to go to the source where it was defined that keywords to comment that out in the first place.

I had to comment out this file /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf where it was firstly defined skip-networking and bind-address.

**/etc/mysql/my.cnf**

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
...
```

I hope this could save time to someone else.